# Add new document as different user

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library

I have a custom webpart which creates some word document and uploads it to a document library on SharePoint site.

By default web part adds document as `System Account`.

Is it possible to use different credentials of some other user to add this document?

I have username and password of that user which I want to use for this, but not sure how to do this

Answer (score 2):

If this is a custom webpart, the custom code is running with System Account and is modifying the changes as per the code. If it is a client side code, you need to pass Credentials through Client context object. It will be something like this:

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://yourserver/")) {
    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
    List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Some List");
    context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Yes, it is custom webpart and I think it runs under System account. It there any way for doing this with custom webpart other than Amal's anwer?

Comment: use the above method..give name and password.. and domain

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are running the upload document code using elevated privileges.

First you should remove that and use impersonation.

In order to impersonate another user you should get the token first using

```
SPUserToken userToken = web.AllUsers[user].UserToken;
```

Then you can create SPSite

```
SPSite site = new SPSite(siteURL, userToken);
```

From this point all the operations you perform using the `site` object will be under the selected user.